# rcarousel slide one at a time, without jump

Tags: jquery

I'm implementing rcarousel with step:1 enabled, however the slider jumps after the last image to put the first image in the first position, instead of just moving 1 slide.  You can see the problem in this example:

http://ryrych.github.com/rcarousel/examples/custom_step_and_visible.html

Is there any option to allow the slider to continuously slide by 1 element on next/prev, without this jump?

```
$( ".carousel" ).rcarousel({
  visible: 4,
  step: 1,
  width: 190, 
  height: 550,
  margin: 65,
  speed: 1000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('.carousel').rcarousel({
 itemOffset: 100,
 infiniteScroll: 1
});
```

Scratch that sorry - You actually solved my problem!

I am using http://labs.juliendecaudin.com/barousel/ instead which I think is better without that jumping step!

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

Try using file b1fb8fb at https://github.com/ryrych/rcarousel/pull/64 to replace the original jquery.ui.rcarousel.js

And in the options, set seamless{ enabled: true,